# Sonarqube 5.1.1 service does not start on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, sonarqube, ubuntu-14.04, init.d

I've followed the installation instruction from http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Running+SonarQube+as+a+Service+on+Linux. Controlling sonarqube works fine using `/usr/bin/sonar` (pointing to `/usr/share/sonarqube-5.1.1/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh`), like

```
root@mars:~# sonar status
SonarQube is running (13597).
```

but not when using:

```
root@mars:~# service sonar status 
root@mars:~#
```

nothing happens. I've setup sonarqube to run as the `sonar` user (not as `root`).

Thus sonarqube does not automatically start during boot which is my real problem.

What should I do to make it work?

Comment: No errors in logs/sonar.log ?

Comment: No entries neither in `sonar.log` nor in `wrapper.log`.

Comment: so the process did not start. I think you need some help about "service", but not about SonarQube.

Comment: The difference between `service sonar start` and `sonar start` is that at some point in the sonar script `su -m sonar -c "/usr/share/sonarqube-5.1.1/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh" start` fails (after having added `set -x` to `sonar.sh`). Should I open an issue with the SonarQube bugtracker?

Comment: did you try `su -m sonar -c "/usr/share/sonarqube-5.1.1/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start"` ? (with the argument `start` in the value of `-c`)

Comment: `+ su -m sonar -c "/usr/share/sonarqube-5.1.1/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start"` fails with 
`bash: /usr/share/sonarqube-5.1.1/bin/linux-x86-64/sonar.sh start: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so I see this is rather old, but perhaps this can help someone else.
I had the same issue with Sonar, the service command would not work with it.

It seemed when using env -i which the service command uses, it starts with an empty environment. Now my sonar system account had /bin/false as a shell, and it would never start the sonar.sh script. When I changed it to /bin/bash, using env -i su - .... worked. So I guess it needs a valid shell if it wants to run using the services command.